# Firebase macOS: Why usage of Auth.auth().currentUser causes SecurityAgent dialog popup while usage of Auth.auth().signInAnonymously is not

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using `FirebaseAuth` on macOS. The below code works as expected. It prints `uid` to console on every app launch.

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
   FirebaseApp.configure()
   Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { [weak self] result, error in
      if let error = error {
         debugPrint(error)
      }
      if let result = result {
         debugPrint(result.user.uid)
      }
   }
}
```

But when using `uid` from `currentUser` property of the `Auth` class the system pops up dialog with the message ***App wants to use your confidential information stored in firebase_auth_1:blah:ios:blah***.

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
   FirebaseApp.configure()
   if let id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
      debugPrint(id) // run `killall -9 SecurityAgent` to kill dialog
   } else {
      Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { [weak self] result, error in
         if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error)
         }
         if let result = result {
            debugPrint(result.user.uid)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[image: SecurityAgent]

How to avoid this system popup when using  `currentUser` property of the `Auth` class?

---

**UPDATE 1** When launching App not from Xcode, but from Finder, the both versions of startup code, shown above, seems working without popping up system dialog. Looks like popup shown only when running app from Xcode.

**UPDATE 2** The issue not in `Auth.auth().currentUser` usage. System shows popup every time when app recompiled. Seems it is depends of the Code signature, which may be different after compiling changes.
[image: Popup]

**UPDATE 3** Seems issue was due Xcode setting "Signing Certificate: **Sign to Run Locally**". Explicitly setting "Provisioning Profile" and "Signing Certificate" solves an issue.
[image: Signing]

Comment: We're also using Firebase on macOS and are not seeing that behavior. Running XCode 11.5 and Firebase SDK 6.3.0. We have sandboxing off totally in XCode and our startup sequence is different. On macOS, the first viewControllers `viewDidLoad` function is called before `applicationDidFinishLaunching` so that's where we initialize Firebase and authenticate - the app just auth's using a single, saved user during testing. If you select Always Allow does it display the dialog after that?

Comment: After allowing with "Always Allow " dialog not appearing. It will appear again after  erasing keychain password item, erasing app container under "~/Library/Containers" and running app from clean build. Looks like it is development time issue related to Sandbox and App registration.